# IE JavaScript documentation

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Anyone knows where can I find the documentation for IE's JavaScript (which functions supports and stuff like that, not stuff specific to the JavaScript language like operators, etc.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the [DHTML reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533050%28VS.85%29.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: +1 @jsoldi: I find that if I do a web search on "msdn functionname" ("msdn getElementsByTagName" for instance) I usually get the MSDN page for that function, if IE supports it, pretty high up on the results list (the top, usually).